# how to get the length of attributes of lidar data in R

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I have an atrribute of an lidar data which i get using the filter_poi  function how do i get the length of this attribute.

Here is my code

```
las <-readLAS("C:\\lid\\Test.las")
las <- filter_poi(las, treeID == i)
```

I want to run a loop on this treeID attribute but i dont the final length of the attribute in order to stop the loop how do i get the length of this attribute in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular R idioms

```r
ids = unique(las$treeID)
```

Comment: I added ids <- length(ids) after the code above which gives me the total length of the attribute

Comment: No it only gives you the number of unique id

Comment: Yes the code you posted only gives me the number of unique id. But i commented that your code plus the length function gives me what i wanted.